# Seed, run code from external file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a ruby file called `company.rb` in **db\company.rb**. This file should create instances of the class `Company` how you can see.

```
list = [["20", "ABC", ...
list.each do |c|
  Company.create(:Key => c[0] ...
end
```

Now i try to make this file run in **db\seeds.rb**. I thought it would be executed if i requiere it in this file like this:

```
require 'company'
```

What do i wrong? Or how can i execute the code from `company.rb` in my `seeds` file? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `db` folder isn't going to be in your load path by default. Your `require 'company'` line is loading the wrong `company.rb` file (probably the one under `app/models`). The easiest solution is to use `require_relative 'company'` (assuming you're not still running Ruby 1.8). You could also:

- Build the path manually with `_FILE_` and `#dirname`.
- Add `db` to your load path (don't do this, it's a bad idea)